# Type-inference fails when binding ReactFx Var.mapBidirectional to JavaFx property

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, type-inference, reactfx

I am trying to bind a `TextField.textProperty()` to a `ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime>` in a custom control. The following code ompiles and runs in Eclipse:

```
package main.java

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.reactfx.value.Var;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Playbook {
    public void bindTimeString(final ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> timepoint, final SimpleStringProperty textProperty) {
        Var.mapBidirectional(textProperty, s -> LocalDateTime.now(), t -> "").bindBidirectional(timepoint);
    }

}
```

However, when I build my application with maven, I get a compilation error:

```
javac -classpath reactfx-2.0-M5.jar Playbook.java
Playbook.java:12: error: no suitable method found for bindBidirectional(ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime>)
        Var.mapBidirectional(textProperty, s -> LocalDateTime.now(), t -> "").bindBidirectional(timepoint);
                                                                             ^
    method Property.bindBidirectional(Property<Object>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> cannot be converted to Property<Object>)
    method Var.bindBidirectional(Property<Object>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> cannot be converted to Property<Object>)
1 error
```

A workaround is to declare a temporary `Var<LocalDateTime` holding the `mapBidirectional` result and then binding it.

```
public void bindTimeString(final ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> timepoint, final SimpleStringProperty textProperty) {
    final Var<LocalDateTime> v = Var.mapBidirectional(textProperty, s -> LocalDateTime.now(), t -> "");
    v.bindBidirectional(timepoint);
}
```

compiles with Eclipse and from the command line with maven as expected.

It feels like a compiler bug in the type inference implementation, but I am not an expert for the Java language spec. I would expect that types can be inferred from the lambda return values. In any case, either Eclipse's java compiler or the JDK compiler is wrong.

Comment: To help the compiler, you can specify the types in your first snippet like this: `Var.<String, LocalDateTime>mapBidirectional`

Comment: @TomasMikula Of course I could specify the types by hand, but the compiler should be smart enough to figure it out for me. It's all there, and the Eclipse compiler does it. I am wondering why the JDK javac fails to do it. BTW, nice work with ReactFx! I wouldn't want to write JavaFx apps without it.