# Why is a `SimpleIntegerProperty` not a `Property<Integer>` but a Property<Number>?

Tags: javafx

While trying to produce a minimal example for the investigation of [another issue with ReactFx's `Var` bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245651/type-inference-fails-when-binding-reactfx-var-mapbidirectional-to-javafx-propert), I stumbled into some IMHO strange implementation of JavaFX's properties. I am trying to use a `SimpleIntegerProperty` as an argument for a function expecting a `Property<Integer>`. However, this does not compile because`SimpleIntegerProperty` does not implement this interface. Instead, it implements `Property<Number>`. I find it strange that I cannot assign `Property<Integer> p = new SimpleIntegerProperty()`, as in the following code:

```
    javafx.beans.property.Property<Integer> p;
    javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty s;

    p = s;
```

I understand why this does not work given the current inheritance hierarchy, but it feels strange and I am looking for the motivation behind the design.

Comment: Why is that weird? ReactFX is a non-official API, and it is building on the official JavaFX property API. You cannot expect the base API to know what the extending API is going to mess with its API. I don't use ReactFX, but from what I see, they probably didn't design it well enough to cover all use cases.

Comment: @Jai It has nothing to do with ReactFx. I was trying to say that in the last paragraph, but it was probabyl not clear enough. I've added an example to show what I mean.

Comment: I think it's an API flaw, fwiw. There should be an abstract `NumberProperty<N extends Number> implements Property<N>` and then `IntegerProperty extends NumberProperty<Integer>`, etc. But with the API as it is, you can, for example, bidirectionally bind an `IntegerProperty` to a `DoubleProperty` (which you may or may not consider a benefit). Note the `asObject()` method, that creates a `Property<Integer>` bidirectionally bound to the `IntegerProperty`, so in your code you can achieve the same thing as you are trying with `p = s.asObject()`